# Error when updating or installing a contrib module with the URL

Tags: 7

I am trying to install a Drupal 7.9 site on a server that hosts several other Drupal sites. I must have gone through this process 50 times before without issue, but now I get an error any time I try to install a module from the URL. Here's an example of the error message with the token module:

```
Downloading updates failed:

Invalid checksum for file " (function ($) { Drupal.behaviors.tokenTree = { attach: function (context, settings) { $('tab" : 42351 calculated, 0 expected
```

There is no error in the log, just this cryptic message that doesn't give me any feedback about the problem.